# How to Collect all System.out.print("") results after running a test suite in TestNG (Selenium with Java)

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am running a test suite which contains TestNG test cases written in Java. I am using an xml file to run the suite in eclipse IDE. Each test case has several System.out.print("") command to print something on the screen. Is there a way to collect all these results from the console and create a file after the test suite is completed?

For example: portion from 2 separate TCs:

```
    //Go to Pricing -->  Scenarios --> Quick Price Scenario 
    driver.get(variables.portalURL + "Portal/Pricing/QuickPrice"); 

    String QP = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.widget-header > h3")).getText();
     if ((QP.equals("Quick Price Scenario"))==true)
     {System.out.println("\nQuick Price Scenario page loaded");
    }
     else  System.out.println("\nQuick Price Scenario page did not load"); 

     //Custom, QP, and Pipeline Go to Pricing -->  Scenarios --> Custom Scenario 
      driver.get(variables.portalURL + "Portal/Pricing/CustomScenario");   
      String CS = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.widget-header > h3")).getText();
      if ((CS.equals("Custom Scenario"))==true)
      {System.out.println("\nCustom Scenario page loaded");    
 }
     else  System.out.println("\nCustom Scenario page did not load");
```

The output will be Quick Price Scenario page loaded. And Custom Scenario page loaded (assuming both true). There will be many more. Is there a way to collect all these in one file when the execution is completed?

Comment: What you are asking for is basically logging - have a look at `slf4j`, `log4j2` and `logback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way collecting the arguments that you passed to `System.out.println(...)` - the method will forward your arguments to `stdout`, without saving them anywhere itself.

Have you thought about using TestNG [`Reporter`](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/Reporter.html)?
This will include all your output in the HML reports TestNG creates.

Another possibility would be to use a logging framework like `log4j` - then you have to replace every call to `System.out.println("...")` with `log.info(...)`, or any other log level you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have never used Reporter in TestNG. Do you have any code that shows how it is being used? If not, I will try to find something online. Using logging framework may not be a clean way to do it for me. Thanks

Comment: I linked the Javadoc, it's quite easy to use. Just call `Reporter.log("your message", true)` - if you don't need the output on `stdout`, you can omit the `true`

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I will look through Reporter and other log you mentioned here. Hopefully, this will give me what I am looking for.